# Searching across tree that is drawn recursively: reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am having tree that is drawn using array of objects recursively. I am able to bring up the tree with all the expand collapse related functionality. Now I want to search across the tree using an input element. This search should happen recursively. When leaf nodes match, the tree should show all the nodes till that leaf node. expanding. when an intermediate or root node is matched, it should show only till that level with collapsed icon, which can then be expanded.

This is what I have tried so far.

Node component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

export const Node = ({ node, level, currentActive, setCurrentActive }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const hasChildren = !!node?.categories?.length;
  const categoryType =
    level === 0 ? "category" : !hasChildren ? "leaf" : "group";
  if (!node) return null;
  const { name, key, categories } = node;
  const activeClassName = currentActive === name ? "active" : "";

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`list-row level-${level} ${categoryType} ${activeClassName}`}
        onClick={() => {
          setIsOpen((open) => !open);
          if (!hasChildren) {
            setCurrentActive((prevName) => (!(prevName === name) ? name : ""));
          }
        }}
        key={key}
      >
        <div className="list-item-holder">
          {hasChildren && (
            <div className="list-item-expander-holder">
              <span
                className={`expand-collapse-icon ${
                  isOpen ? "collapse" : "expand"
                }`}
              >
                <span className="expand-icon">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-down" />
                </span>
                <span className="collapse-icon">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-right" />
                </span>
              </span>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="list-item-details-holder">{name}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {isOpen && hasChildren && (
        <div className="list-row-children">
          {categories.map((node) => (
            <Node
              key={node.key}
              node={node}
              level={level + 1}
              currentActive={currentActive}
              setCurrentActive={setCurrentActive}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

The functionality of search that I tried so far which isnt functional

```
 function searchTree(tree, query) {
    function traverse(node, query) {
      if (node.categories) {
        traverse(node.categories, query);
      }
      return {
        ...node,
        categories: node?.categories?.filter(({ name }) => name === query)
      };
    }
    return tree.map((root) => traverse(root, query));
  }
```

Can someone help as to how this can be implemented. I am just a beginner and trying to learn this. Help would be really appreciated.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-updated-with-search-forked-ms2b6w?file=/src/DrawnTree.jsx:223-617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are a hardcore beginner, what you are trying to do in my opinion is very complex.

I think this is what you described, many changes were necessary, i won't be able to explain all of them, the most important was the logic to keep the parents opened, i created a function that checks if it contains an element with the text, if so, adds `visible` and `opened` properties, that will be used by the node.

Also i renamed `categories` to `nodes` that i think makes more sense

https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-updated-with-search-forked-kbnnmj?file=/src/DrawnTree.jsx

```
  const containsNodesWithTerm = (nodes, searchTerm) => {
    const ids = [];
    const _traverse = (nodes, searchTerm) => {
      nodes.forEach((node) => {
        if (node.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm.toUpperCase())) {
          ids.push(node.key);
        }
        if (node.nodes.length > 0) {
          _traverse(node.nodes, searchTerm);
        }
      });
    };
    _traverse(nodes, searchTerm);
    return ids.length > 0;
  };

  const filterNodes = (nodes, searchTerm = "") => {
    const _filter = (nodes, searchTerm) => {
      nodes.forEach((node) => {
        if (
          node.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm.toUpperCase()) ||
          containsNodesWithTerm(node.nodes, searchTerm)
        ) {
          node.visible = true;
          node.opened = true;
        } else {
          node.visible = false;
        }
        if (!searchTerm) {
          node.opened = false;
        }
        if (node.nodes.length > 0) {
          _filter(node.nodes, searchTerm);
        }
      });
    };
    _filter(nodes, searchTerm);
    return nodes;
  };
```